# Substring in SQL

Tags: sql, string

I have a table

```
doctors (
id int,
name varchar(255)
)
```

where name like "Sername Name".

In query i need only Sername of doctor. How can i do it with standard or with solution on most RDBMS?

I know only two solution.

First is `SUBSTRING(input SIMILAR pattern ESCAPE escape-char)` in postgres is `SUBSTRING(input FROM pattern-string)`.

Second is in postgres like `substring(name, 0 , position(' ')`.

UPD: Is it normal to ask rdbms to split string or better do it manualy in code?

Comment: String manipulation is not consistent in SQL vendors.

Comment: Is it normal to ask rdbms to split string or better do it manualy in  code?

Comment: As I've written in my answer, better do it in the schema (i.e. before inserting the data).

Comment: @inflagranti. I know that this table has bad design, but i have such table. My task is parse string. Question is how to parse string in sql or if it is slow solution make it manually.

Comment: @den bardadym. It is not slower in SQL than in your client code (it even has the advantage that only the relevant portion has to be transfered). It's just much slower and - as, pointed out by mjv, more error prone - than a decent schema.

Comment: @inflagranti. Thanks. I undestand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://sqlnut.atw.hu/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html

Search for `substring` and `position`.

Comment: Furthermore, and not withstanding the possible irregularities introduced in the building of this particular database instance, peoples' names can be irregular enough to make parsing the surname a non trivial task  (ex: mulitiple tokens with "Di Angelo", very short surnames "Le", "Zef"  etc.)

Comment: Thanks for link. It is interesting.

Comment: I accept your answer. Because other answer not for my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, make a schema that doesn't have the surenames and first names mixed in the same column:

```
doctors ( id int, firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255) )
```

Then you don't need those (slow) string operations.